# Joomla link type option

Tags: php, css, joomla

in Joomla 2.5  i add custom images to my menu with link type option.How can i place the text of menu appear under the image?

already tried that

```
$linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" /><br/><span class="image-title">'.$item->title.'</span> ' :
```

but this  don't work

Comment: try making menu images `display:block;` as I assume they are currently `display:inline-block;`

Comment: thanks for reply.Please tall where can i make this change(path)?

Comment: in my tempalte css i change this ..t3-megamenu .nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret {
  display:  inline-block;.    but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening due to the type of display that is assigned to the image. To change it, assign a class to your image like so:

```
$linktype = '<img class="menu_image" ......
```

Once done, open the CSS file for your template and add in the following code:

```
img.menu_image {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry my wrong. this works perfetct! thanks for help

Comment: i add class in css and make it with ispect element , but now cant find where is the path of html to add       $linktype = '<img class="menu_image" ......

Comment: I'm not sure which file it is as the menu is based on the T3 framework. It might be somewhere within the template folder or part of a plugin. Best to check the T3 Framework documentation

Comment: Yes, I know which menu it is, but I'm not going to download it myself and start looking through all the files. You should be looking yourself, or check the documentation, or contact their support

Comment: ok i find it - the path is : root- plugins- system-t3-includes-menu-megamenu.tpl.php            thanks for all help